# Jenkins Multibranch: Indexing error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException

Tags: git, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

I have different multibranch pipelines configured and triggers based on branches, pull requests and tags from `GitHub` repositories.

It was working as expected, but recently I couldn't figure out that repository scan is failing during indexing step with below error.

I am new to `Jenkins` and plugins, need some guidance.

```
ERROR: [Mon Feb 18 06:14:37 UTC 2019] Could not update folder level actions from source HASH

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1902)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:629)

Caused: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: 200, message: 'OK' for URL: GITHUB REPO URL
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:646)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:607)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:285)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:247)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getRepository(GitHub.java:475)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieveActions(GitHubSCMSource.java:1669)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:765)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:591)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1025)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
[Mon Feb 18 06:14:37 UTC 2019] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.27 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the connections somehow failed and returned HTML instead of json; and therefore the Unexpected character '<' error is displayed. Check the Github URL, is 'URL: GITHUB REPO URL' a placeholder? Is there any proxy involved?

Comment: No it's not a placeholder. It's my private repository URL and there is no proxy involved as well. No URLs has been changed. It errors out on all repositories. How do I, as a Jenkins user, debug the response is HTML or JSON and resolve it ?

Comment: `Could not update folder level actions from source HASH` -- this HASH is same for all the jobs (different repositories)